# Convergence of a series with roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Investigate the convergence of $\sum a_n$ when: $$a_n=\frac{\sqrt{n}-1}{2\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$

Which covnergence criterion should i apply here?

Comment: Are you familiar with the limit comparison test?

Comment: i know the method

Comment: Use the limit comparison test with $1/n$.

Comment: Notice that $a_n\sim_\infty \frac1{2\sqrt n}$.

Comment: limit of $\frac{a_n}{ b_n}$ will be $+\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have:

$$\sqrt{n} - 1 \le \sqrt{n}$$

$$n^2 + 1 \ge n^2 \implies \sqrt{n^2 + 1} \ge n \implies 2\sqrt{n^2 + 1} \ge 2n \implies \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} \le \frac{1}{2n}$$

Thus:

$$a_n \le \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2n} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} $$

But: $\sum_{n\ge1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} = \sum_{n\ge1}{\frac{1}{n^{\frac12}}}$ is the Riemann series with power $\alpha = \frac12 \in ]0,1]$, so it's divergent.

This gives $\sum_{n\ge1}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}}$ is divergent.

Therefore by direct comparison test (the two series are non-negative), your series diverges.